# Whats wrong in this Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first

```
var MyCours = Db.COURS.Where(C => C.CLASSE_ID == ClassID
                                        && DateTime.Now>= C.START_DATE
                                        && DateTime.Now <= C.END_DATE)
         .ToList();
```

Some change still dont work !

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: you can't use DateTime class in linq query while fetching from database. Get Datetime.Now to some variable and try to use in linq query. Also, DateTime.Compare can't be used in liq query

Comment: The debugger just jump over it no error displayed !!

Comment: and also START_DATE and END_DATE is of type DateTime? .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A likely problem is that the provider can't project `DateTime.Compare` into a SQL statement. There is potentially also a logical error in the direction of comparison (unless you really want `enddate < now < startdate`), and I would also suggest using `.ToList()` to materialize into a list:

```
var theTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
var MyCours = Db.COURS.Where(C => C.CLASSE_ID == ClassID
                                            && theTimeNow >= C.START_DATE
                                            && theTimeNow <= C.END_DATE)
             .ToList();
```

Projecting `DateTime.Now` into a variable isolates the non-determinism of it, i.e. to ensure that both comparisons are against the same time.